# SignalR Simple Chat Example: Stuck Negotiating

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

Hey so I'm following the SignalR simple example tutorial found [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr). Tasked with creating a chat system. I've finished it up and when I click send nothing happens.

No errors, debugger doesn't get inside the Send method on the Hub class, I had put an alert in the button onclick and it doesn't reach there meaning the  $.connection.hub.start().done(function () is not firing off, so its never reaching done I am guessing.

I turned on logging, and all the log gets to is:

[21:46:52 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)] SignalR: Client subscribed to hub 'chathub'.

[21:46:52 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)] SignalR: Negotiating with '/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.5&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22chathub%22%7D%5D'.

Look at code below:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
                $(function () {
                    // Declare a proxy to reference the hub. 
                    var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
                    $.connection.hub.logging = true;

                    // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
                    chat.client.broadcastMessage = function (name, message) {
                        // Html encode display name and message. 
                        var encodedName = $('<div />').text(name).html();
                        var encodedMsg = $('<div />').text(message).html();
                        // Add the message to the page. 
                        $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + encodedName
                            + '</strong>:&nbsp;&nbsp;' + encodedMsg + '</li>');
                    };
                    // Get the user name and store it to prepend to messages.
                    $('#displayname').val(prompt('Enter your name:', ''));
                    // Set initial focus to message input box.  
                    $('#message').focus();
                    // Start the connection.



                    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                        $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                            // Call the Send method on the hub. 
                            alert($('#message').val());
                            chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
                            // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment. 
                            $('#message').val('').focus();
                        });
                    });
                });
            });</script>
```

Any idea on what the problem is? Debugging this is hell! I've followed the walk-through exactly.

Using Jquery 3, SignalR 2.2.1

Comment: Try to add error handler. `$.connection.hub.error(function (error) { console.log('SignalR error: ' + error) });`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Aleksey! You have solved my issue, I printed out the error ( I didn't know you could), and It was a mismatch between client and server version (1.5 and 1.4). I forgot to update the server portion in Nuget Package Manager.

If someone comes across this problem make sure you've updated all your SignalR libraries to the latest or same version!